# microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp 'obj' is null on at least one execution path

Tags: c#, sql, code-analyst

Такая проблемма: одно из полей в моей модели может быть null. первые два я проверяю.
но на третье (obj.Phone) microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp ругается.

Что нужно сделать, чтоб была возможность передавать null параметр?

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", obj?.Description);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", obj?.Address);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", obj.Phone);
```

Comment: Анализатор ругается не на поле, а на объект `obj`, который в данном контексте может придти в виде `null`.

Comment: Ну и по традиции: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было добавить дополнительную проверку. Так как бд должна принимать именно DBNull.Value, а не обычный null (в противном случае свалится с ошибкой The parameterized query expects the parameter which was not supplied.)

```
(object)obj?.Phone ?? DBNull.Value
```

Comment: Здесь достаточно будет использовать только `obj?.Phone`

Comment: Если к вам придет `obj?.Phone == null` то и в параметр отправится `null`. Чрезмерное усложнение на лицо.

Comment: Другое дело, что в самом первом варианте, если вам приходил объект `obj == null`, то вы валились с ошибкой. на строке `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", obj.Phone);`